# PosqtgreSQL string comparison

Tags: string, postgresql, comparison

I try to compare strings in PostgreSQL.

Here are queries that I execute:

```
select 'UK (z'>'Ukraine';
```

This one returns true;

Then I try following one:

```
select 'UK ('>'Ukraine';
```

This one returns false;

I think, that both of these should return false , and on another PostgreSQL server it behaves correctly. But main server is producing incorrect results in such operations. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Locale (collation) on those two machines?

Comment: On incorrect one - UTF8, on correct - Russian_Russia.1251

Answer (score 1):

If you are in doubt try:

```
SHOW lc_collate;
```

This will show you the default collation.

Now you can specify collation at the column level or the query level.  Since your question is at the query level, you can:

```
select 'UK (z'::text > 'Ukraine' COLLATE "C"; -- and
select 'UK (z'::text > 'Ukraine' COLLATE "ucs_basic"; -- both return false
```

What's actually happening the natural language collation orders ignore whitespace and non-alphanumeric characters, so the first is whether 'UKz' > 'Ukraine' which it is, and the second is whether 'UK' is greater than 'Ukraine' which it is not.

Comment: +1, although _"natural language collation orders ignore whitespace and non-alphanumeric characters"_ is an enormous simplification. `SELECT 'UK (z' > 'UK z';` and `SELECT 'UK z' > 'UKz'` do return `true`.